Python-PPTX copy shape von one PPT to another?
I try to copy a shape from one slide from a PPTX to another slide on another PPTX using the following code:
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
import os
import sys

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
    
      fn = os.path.join(path, "templ2.pptx")
      shapesPPT = Presentation(fn)
      shapesIcons = shapesPPT.slides[0].shapes
    
      fn = os.path.join(path, "templ.pptx")
      ppt = Presentation(fn)
    
      for slide in ppt.slides:
        for shapeIDX, shape in enumerate(slide.shapes):
          if shapeIDX == 7:
            wColor = RGBColor(102, 255, 102)
            # ppt.slides[0].shapes[7].fill.fore_color.rgb = wColor 
            ppt.slides[0].shapes[7] = shapesIcons[15]
    
      fnPPT = os.path.join(path, "OUTPUT", f"output.pptx")
      ppt.save(fnPPT)

But with that i only get this error:
(pptx) C:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\userlutionsgmbh>python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\userlutionsgmbh\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    ppt.slides[0].shapes[7] = shapesIcons[15]
TypeError: 'SlideShapes' object does not support item assignment

When I try to change the fill color (see the commented line above) it works fine. But I want to copy a complete shape from on slide/pptx to another.
How can I do that?
